# TFS Build Definition Argument for Build error

Tags: tfs, build, msbuild, definitions

Is it possible to succeed the failure build through TFS Build Definition even though it has some build errors ? like it should continue on build error
If yes, please provide MSBuild arguments ...

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can tell MSBuild to execute a task and continue on errors (see MSDN articles):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77f2hx1s.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171484.aspx

> ContinueOnError
>   Optional attribute. Can contain one of the following values:
>   WarnAndContinue or true. When a task fails, subsequent tasks in the Target element and the build continue to execute, and all errors from the task are treated as warnings.
>   ErrorAndContinue. When a task fails, subsequent tasks in the Target element and the build continue to execute, and all errors from the task are treated as errors.
>   ErrorAndStop or false (default). When a task fails, the remaining tasks in the Target element and the build aren't executed, and the entire Target element and the build is considered to have failed.
>   Versions of the .NET Framework before 4.5 supported only the true and false values.